# Setting dual bank mode on STM32f779ii

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f7

I'm trying to set dual bank mode for STM32F779II, but it doesn't set at all.

So I tried in the main before doing anything the following code

```
  HAL_FLASH_Unlock();

  HAL_FLASH_OB_Unlock();

  FLASH->OPTCR |= FLASH_OPTCR_nDBANK_Msk;

  HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();

  HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

And When I tried to check if the memory is in Single or Dual Mode:

```
if((OBInit.USERConfig & OB_NDBANK_SINGLE_BANK) == OB_NDBANK_DUAL_BANK){
     printf("Dual bank mode is set");
    }
```

but that statement is never set true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is described in the reference manual.

> To modify the user option value, follow the sequence below:
>
> 1. Check that no Flash memory operation is ongoing by checking the BSY bit in the
>      FLASH_SR register
> 2. Write the desired option value in the FLASH_OPTCR register.
> 3. Set the option start bit (OPTSTRT) in the FLASH_OPTCR register
> 4. Wait for the BSY bit to be cleared.

You have implemented Step 2 only.

Note that to *set dual bank mode*, you have to *clear* that bit.

> Bit 29 nDBANK: Not dual bank mode
>
> 1: The Flash user area is seen as a single bank with 256 bits read access.
>
> 0: The Flash user area is seen as a dual bank with 128 bits read access (dual bank mode feature active)

Comment: Can you show some pseudocode for the full process as a reference here

Comment: What do you mean by pseudocode? Do steps 1, 2, 3, 4 in this order, no branches or whatever are required.