# Running a software from a flash STM32F779II

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f7

I would like to run my firmware from the flash address :0x08040000

so I partitioned the memory layout for the software as shown:

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20080000;    /* end of RAM */

/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x1000;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x2000; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
  FLASH  (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x08040000, LENGTH = 768K
  FLASH2 (r)   : ORIGIN = 0x08100000, LENGTH = 1024K
  SRAM1 (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20020000, LENGTH = 368K
  SRAM2 (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x2007C000, LENGTH = 16K
  DTCMRAM (wal) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
  MEMORY_B1 (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0K
}

main_stack_base = _estack;
/* used by the startup code to populate variables used by the C code */
data_lma = LOADADDR(.data);
data_vma = ADDR(.data);
data_size = SIZEOF(.data);

/* used by the startup code to wipe memory */
ccmram_start = ORIGIN(SRAM1);
ccmram_end = ORIGIN(SRAM1) + 4;

/* used by the startup code to wipe memory */
sram_start = ORIGIN(SRAM1);
sram_end = ORIGIN(SRAM1) + LENGTH(SRAM1);
_ram_start = sram_start;
_ram_end = sram_end;

_codelen = LENGTH(FLASH);
_flash_start = ORIGIN(FLASH);
_flash_end = ORIGIN(FLASH) + LENGTH(FLASH);

_heap_start = ADDR(.heap);
_heap_end = ADDR(.heap) + SIZEOF(.heap);





/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH


  .flash2 : ALIGN(512) {
    build/firmware_rnc/frozen_mpy.o(.rodata*);
    build/firmware_rnc/vendor/secp256k1-zkp/src/secp256k1.o(.rodata*);
    . = ALIGN(512);
  } >FLASH2 AT>FLASH2


  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH2 AT>FLASH2

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >SRAM1 AT> FLASH

  _sidtcmram = LOADADDR(.dtcmram);

  /* DTCMRAM section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section, 
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .dtcmram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdtcmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at dtcmram start */
    *(.dtcmram)
    *(.dtcmram*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edtcmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at dtcmram end */
  } >DTCMRAM AT> FLASH

 _sisram2 = LOADADDR(.sram2);

  /* SRAM2 section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section, 
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .sram2 :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ssram2 = .;       /* create a global symbol at sram2 start */
    *(.sram2)
    *(.sram2*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _esram2 = .;       /* create a global symbol at sram2 end */
  } >SRAM2 AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >SRAM1



   .heap : ALIGN(4) {
    . = 37K; /* this acts as a build time assertion that at least this much memory is available for heap use */
    . = ABSOLUTE(sram_end - 16K); /* this explicitly sets the end of the heap effectively giving the stack at most 16K */
  } >SRAM1

  .stack : ALIGN(8) {
    . = 4K; /* this acts as a build time assertion that at least this much memory is available for stack use */
  } >SRAM1



  /* MEMORY_bank1 section, code must be located here explicitly            */
  /* Example: extern int foo(void) __attribute__ ((section (".mb1text"))); */
  .memory_b1_text :
  {
    *(.mb1text)        /* .mb1text sections (code) */
    *(.mb1text*)       /* .mb1text* sections (code)  */
    *(.mb1rodata)      /* read-only data (constants) */
    *(.mb1rodata*)
  } >MEMORY_B1

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

My startup looks like this:

```
 .syntax unified
  .cpu cortex-m7
  .fpu softvfp
  .thumb

.global  g_pfnVectors
.global  Default_Handler

/* start address for the initialization values of the .data section. 
defined in linker script */
.word  _sidata
/* start address for the .data section. defined in linker script */  
.word  _sdata
/* end address for the .data section. defined in linker script */
.word  _edata
/* start address for the .bss section. defined in linker script */
.word  _sbss
/* end address for the .bss section. defined in linker script */
.word  _ebss
/* stack used for SystemInit_ExtMemCtl; always internal RAM used */

/**
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor first
 *          starts execution following a reset event. Only the absolutely
 *          necessary set is performed, after which the application
 *          supplied main() routine is called. 
 * @param  None
 * @retval : None
*/

    .section  .text.Reset_Handler
  .weak  Reset_Handler
  .type  Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:  
  ldr   sp, =_estack      /* set stack pointer */

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */  
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sidata
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr  r0, =_sdata
  ldr  r3, =_edata
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyDataInit
  ldr  r2, =_sbss
  b  LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */  
FillZerobss:
  movs  r3, #0
  str  r3, [r2], #4

LoopFillZerobss:
  ldr  r3, = _ebss
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  FillZerobss

/* Call the clock system intitialization function.*/
  bl  SystemInit   
/* Call static constructors */

/* Call the application's entry point.*/
  bl  main
  bx  lr    
.size  Reset_Handler, .-Reset_Handler
```

The problem is: The firmware doesn't enter the main function and it jumps somewhere in one of the .c files always doing that.
Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of the reset vector is determined by the

- logic level on the BOOT pin at reset
- contents of the nDBANK and nDBOOT bits in the user option bytes
- contents of the boot address option bytes

Verify that *all* of these contain the right values according to chapters 2.5 and and 3.4 of the reference manual.

If they still have their default values, and the BOOT pin is pulled low, the cpu will use the value at 0x08000004 with bit 0 cleared as the start address, and the value at 0x08000000 as the initial stack pointer. You can either copy the first 8 bytes from the start of the image to 0x08000000 in the flash, or set an alternate address in the option bytes.

Comment: I have already written a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757204/setting-dual-bank-mode-on-stm32f779ii/57758380#57758380) on how to set an option bit. Which step do you have trouble with?

Comment: Where should I set the options bits to the section of the flash ? In main.c ?  Can you show some code where I let mcu boot from 8000400